# Parsing value from search field to http request

Tags: php, html, rest

Having two pages.

http://miveo.dk/searchform.php
http://miveo.dk/search.php?go

I'm trying to parse the input value from the search form into a http request done in php and curl.

Check the lines where is says: Look here.

I did echo out the $name value and got the valued parsed correctly. But it won't get parsed into the HTTP request I try to do.

Any ideas what I do wrong?
Search.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
if(preg_match("/[A-Z  | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])){ 
$name = $_POST['name'];       <-- LOOK HERE
$url  = 'http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=28';
$url .= '&apiKey=nwdzm6ph8j8qss4yg8w7pyfy';
$url .= '&cid=55505';
$url .= '&destinationString=$name'; <---- LOOK HERE
$url .= '&searchRadius=50';
$url .= '&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED';
$url .='&arrivalDate=09/04/2015&departureDate=09/05/2015&room1=2';
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

} 
  else{ 
  echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>"; 
  }
}
} 
?> 
<table>
<Tr>
<TD>
<?PHP
echo $name;
//for ($x=0; $x <=9; $x++)
//{
//print_r($url);
print_r("<BR>");
print_r("<pre>");
print_r ($response);
print_r("</pre>");
//}
?>
</TD>
</Tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need either:

```
$url .= "&destinationString=$name"; <---- LOOK HERE
```

or

```
$url .= '&destinationString=' . $name; <---- LOOK HERE
```

PHP only does variable substitution in a double-quoted string, not a single-quoted string.